# Create a new child node using a for-each in XSL

Tags: xml, xslt

I have found multiple tutorials, articles, posts etc. regarding xsl:for-each but none that seem to match my use case so apologies if this has already been answered elsewhere.

I have the following example XML (There are multiple doc items):

```
<doc>
  <att>
     <PRef>52545125</PRef>
     <BlobContent Name="rtf" ID="A7A9348763A111EA887800505685156C">
        <Property Name="MimeType" Value="application/rtf"/>
        <Property Name="FileName" Value="P0001A__m.rtf"/>
        <Reference Link="Directory\export_819280402327681192_P0001A__m.rtf"
                   Type="RELATIVEFILE"/>
     </BlobContent>
     <InvoiceDate>01/01/1970</InvoiceDate>
     <NetAmount>100.75</NetAmount>
     <GrossAmount/>
     <BlobContent Name="tif" ID="A7A90D7663A111EA887800505685156C">
        <Property Name="MimeType" Value="image/tiff"/>
        <Property Name="FileName" Value="P0001A__m.tif"/>
        <Reference Link="Directory\export_4747308861722121077_P0001A__m.tif"
                   Type="RELATIVEFILE"/>
     </BlobContent>
  </att>
```

I'm attempting to change the following from each BlobContent

```
<Reference Link="Directory\export_4747308861722121077_P0001A__m.tif" Type="RELATIVEFILE"/>
```

to read as:

```
<rtf>Directory\export_819280402327681192_P0001A__m.rtf</rtf>
<tif>Directory\export_4747308861722121077_P0001A__m.tif</tif>
```

The following xsl will work as expected but puts the data into  tags with nothing to define is this is the tif or rtf:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
  version="2.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  
  <xsl:template match="/doc/att/BlobContent/Reference">
    <xsl:variable name="element-name" select="@Link"/>
    <xsl:element name="Link">
      <xsl:value-of select="@Link"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>



</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I've tried adding a for-each to create the new tags based on the BlobContent name but get an error  stating {tif rtf} is an invalid QName so it seems to be picking up each value but grouping them into a single element name.

Thanks

Comment: Where is the value of  `tif` or `rtf` supposed to come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a template

```
  <xsl:template match="/doc/att/BlobContent/Reference">
    <xsl:element name="{../@Name}">
      <xsl:value-of select="@Link"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
```

Comment: I ended up doing it this way, thanks for the advise.